# Run Nested MySQL queries with PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a MySQL nested query I want to run in PDO. When I run the query in the phpmyAdmin console it executes successfully. However it does not execute with the pdo code in php file.

below is the code:

```
 try{   

     $dbh->beginTransaction();   
  $stmt2 = $dbh->prepare( "INSERT INTO `members`( `username`, `email`, `password`, `time_created`) 
  VALUES (:username , :email , :password , NOW());
  INSERT INTO `members_groups` (`member_id` , `group_id`) 
   VALUES((SELECT MAX(member_id) FROM members) , 
   (SELECT group_id FROM groups WHERE permission = 0 ))
             ");

$stmt2->bindParam('username', $username , PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt2->bindParam(':email', $email , PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt2->bindParam(':password', $password , PDO::PARAM_STR);     
    if($stmt2->execute()){
    $dbh->commit(); 
    echo "registered successfully";             
    }
  }
 catch (Exception $e){
    $dbh->rollback();
    echo "an error has occurred";
  }
```

when I run the code it says run successfully but nothing goes into the table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have forgotten the ':' at the start of the parameter name in your first bindParam call.

Also, I kind of doubt that PDO::prepare can handle multiple statements. You should probably split it up into two separately prepared and executed statements.

Answer (score 0):

Your query should fail if you have more than one row in `groups` that matches the `WHERE` condition.  This version should at least parse correctly:

```
INSERT INTO `members_groups`(`member_id` , `group_id`) 
    SELECT m.member_id, g.group_id
    FROM (SELECT MAX(member_id) as member_id FROM members
         ) m CROSS JOIN
         (SELECT group_id
          FROM groups
          WHERE permission = 0
         ) g;
```

However, you might still get a duplicate key error, if you duplicates are encountered and you have a uniqueness constraint.